# Wall of Flesh battle advice

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I play Terraria on mobile and I'm getting bored. I would like to get to hard mode. I have tried 4 times without succes. The final is getting super close, but I keep getting killed by a hell bat. Is there a way to get rid of other mobs or any other overall advice?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem IMO it depends on the differences between the WoF fight on PC vs. the WoF fight on mobile.

Comment: Afaik, there are no differences. Certainly nothing significant.

Comment: Are on the PC version or mobile?

Answer (score 0):

My advice for defeating the WoF would be to gear up in full meteorite armour with a space gun as with the armour you have infinite ammo (no mana cost). Then I would stack up with healing potions as well as some accessories that buff your defence. Get a good spear for dealing with close range enemies.

With this setup you should easily do it.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what Sulphate said...

Get the best gear that you can pre-hardcore. But I'd add to that to build a "MEGA-BRIDGE" so you don't have to bother too much about moving around so you can just run backwards.

You can also do that with a cart and rails but it gives you a lot less mobility.

Comment: Cart and rails might be better if you don't have Hermes Boots (but you should have them by then)

Comment: Even then, you can't really move properly. If you don't have either hermes boots or a grappling hook, your bound to have a bad time.

Comment: Not to mention you'll need so much iron you're bound to find boots along the way.